# "Eval" a string in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, eval

I'm trying to "eval" a string representing an OCaml expression in OCaml. I'm looking to do something equivalent to Python's [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

So far I've not been able to find much. The [Parsing](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Parsing.html) module looks like it could be helpful, but I was not able to find a way to just eval a string.

Comment: Could you give details on your precise use case ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how to do it, but I didn't tell you. (Also the Parsing module is about Parsing, not executing code)

```
#require "compiler-libs" (* Assuming you're using utop, if compiling then this is the package you need *)
let eval code =
  let as_buf = Lexing.from_string code in
  let parsed = !Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase as_buf in
  ignore (Toploop.execute_phrase true Format.std_formatter parsed)
```

example:

```
eval "let () = print_endline \"hello\";;"
```

Notice the trailing `;;` in the code sample.

To use `ocamlbuild`, you will need to use both `compiler-libs` and `compiler-libs.toplevel`.

Comment: This answer absolutely works in UTop, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with ocamlbuild. I'm requiring the same "compiler-libs" package (`-pkg compiler-libs`), but a get the error `Reference to undefined global 'Toploop'`

Comment: Actually, I figured it out and have edited your answer to reflect the correct package!

Comment: @lezed1 Okay but I really recommend you not use this, its completely side stepping the type system.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml is a compiled (not interpreted) language. So there's no simple way to do this. Certainly there are no language features that support it (as there are in almost every interpreted language). About the best you could do would be to link your program against the OCaml toplevel (which is an OCaml interpreter).

Comment: I was thinking about using the functionality of top-level or utop. How can I link against it to provide eval like functionality? I think this is a useful file, but I can't figure out how to use it. https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/toplevel/toploop.ml

Comment: Also, this seems to be the actual Parser used by top-level: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/53fff352723eddd14baac86bc5fd187b4c74223b/parsing/parser.mly

Comment: @lezed1You can do it....ie compile it on the file and then exec the code, but this is the wrong way to code in OCaml. (Compiler-libs is where to look)